# How to use List<? extends Map<String, ?>>

Tags: java, android, list

I'm trying to use a constructor of a library i'm using.
But i need to pass it this object :

```
 List<? extends Map<String, ?>>
```

But i have only an object :

```
 data = ArrayList<MyOwnObject>.
```

I don't understand how i adapt my data to fit in `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`.

Thanks.

Comment: `MyOwnObject` must extend `Map<String, ?>`

Comment: MyOwnObject must extend Map<String, ?>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. That `<? extends Whatever>` is called a *bounded wildcard*. It will only match your `ArrayList<YourObject>` if `YourObject` belongs to a class implements `Map<String, Something>`, where `Something` can be any class (that one will match the *unbounded wildcard* `?`).

Your `ArrayList` is totally fine, since that implements the `List` interface. It's your custom `MyOwnObject` that needs to satisfy the above restrictions.

Read more about wildcards [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: Ok, MyOwnObject is already extending an other class but i can modify that. It's working now. It's just weird because my object is extending a map<> but i'm not using any of the map<> features.

Comment: If you use newer java (not in eclipse), you get "error: incompatible types: List<Map> cannot be converted to List<? extends Map<String,?>>"  I haven't found a workaround to this yet.